# Is the naturals to the reals a bijection of the reals to the Naturals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the naturals to the reals ~ of the reals to the Naturals?

I know this has to do with the cantor-bernstein theorem, and it needs to be split up into 2 theorems because of it.

Comment: What does the ~ mean? There certainly is no bijection, however.

Comment: Didn't understand your question

Comment: Help me clarify your question. Did you mean to ask: "Is the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ equipotent to the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{N}$?"

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Note that $2^\Bbb R\subseteq\Bbb N^\Bbb R$. On the other hand $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb N^\Bbb N$ have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

Any map $\Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is at best an injection. The cardinality of $\Bbb{R}$ far exceeds the cardinality of the natural numbers, so no map is onto. Hence, no bijection exists. Check out Cantor's Diagonal argument that $[0,1)$ is uncountable. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Numbers_are_Uncountable/Cantor%27s_Diagonal_Argument